# Process a list of tasks without concurrency

Tags: c#, async-await

Given this list:

```cs
var tasks = new List<Task>
{
    MyMethod1,
    MyMethod2,
    MyMethod3
};
```

And these methods:

```
async Task MyMethod1()
{
    await SomeOtherMethod1();
}

async Task MyMethod2()
{
    await SomeOtherMethod2();
}

async Task MyMethod3()
{
    await SomeOtherMethod3();
}
```

Is it possible to do this where each `task` completes in order (no concurrency):

```cs
foreach (var task in tasks)
{
    await task;
}
```

I haven't been able to find any way or examples where this is done. `foreach` just fires them all off. There is `await foreach`, but `Task` doesn't contain a public instance or extension definition for `GetAsyncEnumerator`.

Comment: What about calling `task.Wait()`? You'll block the thread, but it sounds like that's what you want.

Comment: Could you tell more about the `MyTask1`, `MyTask2` and `MyTask3`? Are these variables or methods?

Comment: `await` doesn't determine when they finish, it just simply waits for them to finish. You'll need to call `Task.Start()` somewhere or your `await` line will just wait infinitely. I think the important thing here is the order in which they're started, not necessarily the order in which they're awaited.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias They are methods. I will update the question.

Comment: Are they CPU or IO-bound?

Comment: I tried `task.Wait()`, as well as adding a `task.Start()` before it. Still seeing the execution overlap.

Comment: How can you add a method in a `List<Task>`? Is it possible that you are invoking these methods, and you are adding their `Task` results in the list?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I added more detail about the async methods to the question.

Comment: Have you checked that the code compiles?

Comment: Yes, it runs. It's just that the methods' execution overlaps.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you everyone for the comments and answers. The answers really got me to a solution. I upvoted both answers. I'm putting an answer here, because it updates the code in the question to a working version that I'm using.

```cs
var tasks = new List<Func<Task>>
{
    async () => await MyMethod1,
    async () => await MyMethod2,
    async () => await MyMethod3
};
```

```cs
foreach (var task in tasks)
{
    await Task.Run(task);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

`foreach` doesn't start the tasks. [By convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058), tasks are returned "hot" - that is, already running. So, the very fact that you *have* a list of tasks implies they are already running concurrently.

If you want to create a list of asynchronous actions to execute in the future (i.e., asynchronous delegates), then you want to use a `List<Func<Task>>` instead of a `List<Task>`, and then you can `foreach` over each delegate, invoking it and `await`ing the returned task.

Answer (score 1):

Do u mean you want to wait for them to finish one by one by their order?

You can do something simple like a regular for loop (actually foreach should  have the same results) and .Wait() or I didn't fully understand what you are trying to achieve...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestStuff
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task t1 = new Task(() => {
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                Console.WriteLine("I'm T1! I'm done!");
            });

            Task t2 = new Task(() => {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Console.WriteLine("I'm T2! I'm done!");
            });


            Task t3 = new Task(() => {
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                Console.WriteLine("I'm T3! I'm done!");
            });


            List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>() { t1, t2, t3 };

            for (int i = 0; i < tasks.Count; i++)
            {
                tasks[i].Start();
                tasks[i].Wait();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `for()` could be replaced with `tasks.ForEach(t => t.Start()); Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());`.

Comment: @PaulSinnema if you start all the tasks at once, you'll get concurrency. Which is exactly what the OP does**n't** want.